# unresolved type error from classes imported from external jar file

Tags: java, android, eclipse, fuzzy-logic

I'm creating an android application using fuzzy logic. I have imported the jar library by adding it to the lib folder.

However, the classes that refer to these libraries show an error *"couldn't be resolved to a type"*.

I tried the solution, [classes from android project library not resolved in android project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16924457/classes-from-android-project-library-not-resolved-in-android-project). But it didn't work for me and the clean-refresh-build method too wasn't useful.

The code:

```
import java.sql.Savepoint;

import com.fuzzylite.*;
import com.fuzzylite.defuzzifier.*;
import com.fuzzylite.factory.*;
import com.fuzzylite.hedge.*;
import com.fuzzylite.imex.*;
import com.fuzzylite.norm.*;
import com.fuzzylite.norm.s.*;
import com.fuzzylite.norm.t.*;
import com.fuzzylite.rule.*;
import com.fuzzylite.term.*;
import com.fuzzylite.variable.*;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RatingBar;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

private void fuzzy(){
    Engine engine = new Engine();
    engine.setName("Mamdani-Tip-Calculator");

    InputVariable inputVariable1 = new InputVariable();
    inputVariable1.setEnabled(true);
    inputVariable1.setName("FoodQuality");
    inputVariable1.setRange(1.000, 10.000);
    inputVariable1.addTerm(new Trapezoid("Bad", 0.000, 1.000, 3.000, 7.000));
    inputVariable1.addTerm(new Trapezoid("Good", 3.000, 7.000, 10.000, 11.000));
    engine.addInputVariable(inputVariable1);

    InputVariable inputVariable2 = new InputVariable();
    inputVariable2.setEnabled(true);
    inputVariable2.setName("Service");
    inputVariable2.setRange(1.000, 10.000);
    inputVariable2.addTerm(new Trapezoid("Bad", 0.000, 1.000, 3.000, 7.000));
    inputVariable2.addTerm(new Trapezoid("Good", 3.000, 7.000, 10.000, 11.000));
    engine.addInputVariable(inputVariable2);

    OutputVariable outputVariable = new OutputVariable();
    outputVariable.setEnabled(true);
    outputVariable.setName("Tip");
    outputVariable.setRange(0.000, 30.000);
    outputVariable.fuzzyOutput().setAccumulation(new AlgebraicSum());
    outputVariable.setDefuzzifier(new Centroid(200));
    outputVariable.setDefaultValue(Double.NaN);
    outputVariable.setLockValidOutput(false);
    outputVariable.setLockOutputRange(false);
    outputVariable.addTerm(new Gaussian("AboutTenPercent", 10.000, 2.000));
    outputVariable.addTerm(new Gaussian("AboutFifteenPercent", 15.000, 2.000));
    outputVariable.addTerm(new Gaussian("AboutTwentyPercent", 20.000, 2.000));
    engine.addOutputVariable(outputVariable);

    RuleBlock ruleBlock = new RuleBlock();
    ruleBlock.setEnabled(true);
    ruleBlock.setName("");
    ruleBlock.setConjunction(new AlgebraicProduct());
    ruleBlock.setDisjunction(new Maximum());
    ruleBlock.setActivation(new Minimum());
    ruleBlock.addRule(Rule.parse("if FoodQuality is Bad and Service is Bad then Tip is AboutTenPercent", engine));
    ruleBlock.addRule(Rule.parse("if FoodQuality is Bad and Service is Good then Tip is AboutFifteenPercent", engine));
    ruleBlock.addRule(Rule.parse("if FoodQuality is Good and Service is Bad then Tip is AboutFifteenPercent", engine));
    ruleBlock.addRule(Rule.parse("if FoodQuality is Good and Service is Good then Tip is AboutTwentyPercent", engine));
    engine.addRuleBlock(ruleBlock);


}
```

ScreenShots:

[The imported libraries do not seem to have a problem.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vQNZx.png)

[The classes cannot be resolved to a type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SknqN.png)

Comment: Does anything change if you import the single classes instead of packages? ie. import com.fuzzylite.Engine instead of com.fuzzylite.*

Comment: Did you save and autobuild?....sry

Comment: @user2504380 - Yes, I tried save and autobuild, but no result.

Comment: @Giovanni - Engine is a java file in the fuzzylite folder. I have included the screenshots in the question, that may help you understand the problem. I had created the jar file by converting the zip file using an online convertor. Can that be a problem?

Answer (score 0):

Where have you imported the jfuzzylite.jar file? I think you should see the jfuzzylite.jar file within the referenced libraries.

Have you tried building the jfuzzylite.jar using `ant` on the build.xml file provided with jfuzzylite?